# invalid implication from weak statement to strong

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$(\forall y \exists x Text(x,y)) \Rightarrow (\exists x \forall y Text(x,y))$ where Text($x$,$y$) means "$x$ sends a text to $y$"

Why is this statement invalid? My interpretation of the two statements is as follows:

Left:

> Everybody gets a text from somebody

Right:

> There is somebody that texts everybody

Now, it is pretty obvious that the first doesn't imply the second, but how do I actually prove this with a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from the chat rooms, I came up with the following answer:

Consider a universe with 3 people A,B,C. A gets a text from B, B gets a text from C and C gets a text from B. This satisfies the first statement, but definitely doesn't imply the second because there is no single person who texts everybody.

Comment: Yes, that suffices.